# Prevent stepper-motor heating in constant torque situation

Tags: stepper-motor

I am using multiple stepper motors in an application where each motor is always resisting some torque, i.e. if I turn off the power to a motor, the applied torque will cause it to rotate and lose its position which I do not want. Therefore, the motors are being run at full power for the duration of the tests (which includes periods of rotation as well as stationary periods). Constantly applying full power causes the motors to heat up rapidly. What techniques are available for using stepper motors under constant torque conditions while minimizing heat production? I am using a Quadstepper board (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10507) to drive four motors.

Comment: If you need the high current to drive the steppers then they will heat up with a simple driver.  Some (more so consumer) devices have a lower holding current that is managed by the driver internally or with firmware help. This driver does not support low current idle. You may have to select larger motors or cool them with fan or heatsink.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I'd suggest a rethink of your philosophy. If ever this was a situation that called for the inclusion of a brake on your motors, this is it. What you want is brake that is normally engaged, and so will draw no power during your stationary periods.

Answer (score 0):

The current (and therefore heat expended) from a stepper is **highest in exactly** the state you describe -- holding a commanded position.  So if you want to get rid of the heat, you must power down the motor when the rotary position is unchanging.  I would suggest a a mechanical brake, or mechanical pawl system.